# Можно ли в андроид получить схем WiFi?

Tags: android

Можно ли в андроид получить схем WiFi? Тоесть чтобы подключиться к Wifi и узнать его радиус?
Зону покрытия

Comment: Зону покрытия можно узнать, только походив вокруг точки доступа и посмотрев на уровеь сигнала. А вот радиуса у WiFi нет.

Comment: что вообще такое *схем*? Такого слова не существует. А раз вы его использовали аж 2 раза, то это должно быть не описка...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вайфай не знает свой радиус покрытия. Если вы положите роутер в свинцовый ящик, радиус покрытия у него будет ~5 см. А если поднимете на высоту 20м., и поставите внешнюю антенну, то он достигнет 200м.в прямой видимости (вполне возможно).

Все зависит от условий окружающей среды.